# What permission is needed to upload extensions to TFS2015?

Tags: tfs

What is the required permission to upload TFS extensions to on-premise TFS2015 Update2 ?

We have couple of developers works on custom build extensions, it looks like we need to add those developers as admin on the whole TFS instance (granted through TFS Administration console on application tier).

Anyone known if there is a way to grant only "upload extension permissions" permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload extensions, you have to be a member of TFS Administration Console Users.

Since extensions affect and are available to everyone on the server this is the correct and expected behaviour. Ideally they would submit their extensions to you (the administrator) and you can validate them on a test instance before depoying to production.

I would recommend that you create an automated build and release pipeline with Release Management to automate this. The administrator can the. Simply approve the deployment.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: Thanks very much! We will look into automate the process.